# Check for NaN values in some particular column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
     a   b   c
  0  1   2  NaN
  1  2   NaN  4
  3  Nan 4  NaN
```

I want to check for NaN in only some particular column's and want the resulting dataframe as:

```
     a   b   c
  0  1   2  NaN
  3  Nan 4  NaN
```

Here I want to check for NaN in only Column 'a' and Column 'c'.
How this can be done?

Comment: So you want to get rid of rows that don't have any NaN values?  The way the question is phrased is not particularly clear.

Comment: @ajcr I added some more details to my post. I hope now the question is clear to you.

Comment: So you want to find `NaN` in particular column and drop them? In your example if you'll subset with `'a'` and `'b'` columns only `0` row will left..

Comment: No I don't want to drop them. I want the resulting dataframe to contain only those rows where column 'a' and column 'b' contain NaN.

Comment: But your expecting result doesn't contain `NaN` from `'b'` column...

Comment: sorry It was my mistake. It was column 'a' and column 'c'. As in my dataframe row number - 1 doesn't contain NaN in column 'a' and column 'c', thats why I have excluded it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) methods:

```
In [264]: df
Out[264]: 
    a  b   c
0   1  2 NaN
1   2  NaN   4
2 NaN  4 NaN

In [265]: df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
Out[265]: 
    a  b   c
0   1  2 NaN
2 NaN  4 NaN
```

*Note: if you just want clear rows without any `NaN` you could use `dropna` method*

**EDIT**

If you want to subset your dataframe you could use mask with your columns and apply it to the whole dataframe:

```
df_subset = df[['a', 'c']]

In [282]: df[df_subset.isnull().any(axis=1)]
Out[282]: 
    a  b   c
0   1  2 NaN
2 NaN  4 NaN
```

Comment: I want to check for null only in some particular column. Not all the columns. Check my post I added some more details there.

Comment: Thanks :). I got my answer.